# HighStock xDateFormat month name

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighStock to display a stockChart. The XAxis of the HighStock chart is datetime.

How can I display the full month name in the tooltip's header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent almost a full hour digging for the **%B** key. Hopefully it'll help someone else trying to achieve something similar.

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b>',
    xDateFormat: '%B %Y',
    ....
```

Comment: You could also use `Highcharts.dateFormat` function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.dateFormat). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2qrfsonv/.

Comment: I am using it in Gantt Chart by HighCharts and it is really helpful.